# Filtering a String for a Set of Characters

Tags: python

this is from the 'python cookbook' but isn't explained that well.

```
allchars = string.maketrans('','')
def makefilter(keep):
    delchars = allchars.translate(allchars, keep)
    def thefilter(s):
        return s.translate(allchars,delchars)
    return thefilter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    just_vowels = makefilter('aeiou')
    print just_vowels('four score and seven years ago')

    print just_vowels('tigere, igers, bigers')
```

my question is, how does thefilters 's' get passed in as a parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makefilter` returns a function.

In the example code:

```
just_vowels = makefilter('aeiou')
```

the variable `just_vowels` now refers to a function based on `thefilter`.

The code:

```
print just_vowels('tigere, igers, bigers')
```

is calling that function, and setting its `s` parameter to the string `'tigere, igers, bigers'`.

Comment: ahhh...so thefilter isn't run in the initial makerfilter.  It waits to be called later...

Comment: Correct.  `makefilter` is creating a "closure", which is a function that "waits to be called later" as you put it, and also carries with it some state that it obtained at the time it was created (`delchars` in this case).

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to simplify that cookbook code using a list comprehension or generator expression:

```
def make_filter(keep):
    def the_filter(string):
        return ''.join(char for char in string if char in keep)
    return the_filter
```

This will work the same way as the provided makefilter.

```
>>> just_vowels = make_filter('aeiou')
>>> just_vowels('four score and seven years ago')
'ouoeaeeeaao'
>>> just_vowels('tigere, igers, bigers')
'ieeieie'
```

Like Richie explained, it will dynamically create a function, which you can later call on a string. The `(char for char in string if char in keep)` bit of code creates a generator which will iterate over the characters of the original string and perform the filtering. `''.join(...)` then combines those characters back into a string.

Personally, I find that level of abstraction (writing a function to return a function) to be overkill for this sort of problem. It's a question of taste, but I think your code would be clearer if you just call the significant line directly:

```
>>> string = 'tigere, igers, bigers'
>>> keep = 'aeiou'
>>> ''.join(char for char in string if char in keep)
'ieeieie'
```

Comment: You really should not use keywords in the example...  
`''.join(x for x in input_string if x in keep)`